# Trigger autoplay in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

As autoplay of *audio/video* in **mobile browsers** is not allowed, I'm trying to workaround the autoplay to work, but failed. I tried to bind the `play()` event to `document.ready()` and also with `loadstart` but nothing works. Below are my failed attempts

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', '<%= cloudinary_url(@audio.url, resource_type: "video") %>');
```

Attempt #1

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ('.play').trigger('click');
});

$(document).on('click','.play', function(){
  audioElement.play();// this didn't worked
  $(".play").hide();
  $(".pause").show();
});
```

Attempt #2

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  audioElement.addEventListener('loadstart', function(){
    audioElement.play(); // this didn't worked too
    $(".play").hide();
    $(".pause").show();
  });
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: It cannot be done before user interaction